# Cypress: how to test loadmore button

Tags: cypress

I have a load more button loading posts and a Cypress test covering the loading action. How I could tell to Cypress to repeat the step until the button disappears (eg nothing to load any longer?). If I don't know how many times I need to click?

One iteration I check the following way:

```
cy.get('#loadmore').click();
cy.get('#loadmore').contains(text.loading);

cy.wait('@loadPosts')

cy.get('.blog').find('.article').should('have.length', n+5)
cy.get('#loadmore').contains(text.loadmore)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI this is not the correct behavior of e2e tests because you should always know how many times you have to click a button.
But as a workaround I guess you can use something like this:

```
// your cypress test code
it('does something different based on the class of the button', function () {
  // RERUN THIS TEST OVER AND OVER AGAIN
  // AND IT WILL SOMETIMES BE TRUE, AND
  // SOMETIMES BE FALSE.

  cy.get('button').then(($btn) => {
    if ($btn.hasClass('active')) {
      // do something if it's active
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  })
})
```

Reference link https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#The-DOM-is-unstable